# ¿Como llamar a un modal desde otra página con Ajax y enviarle datos?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

Buenas tengo el siguiente código del primer modal en donde trato de llamar al segundo modal desde una segunda página llamada "modal.php" a través de Ajax.

```
<div class="modal " id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Formulario</h5>
            <label for=""> </label>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="form_id" action="<?= makeUrl(["page" => "test/extra/details"]) ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input name="color_update" type="hidden" id="txtColor" value="#85C1E9">
              <input name="start" type="hidden" id="start" readonly>
              <input name="startStr" type="hidden" id="startStr" readonly>
              <input type="hidden" name="title" id="title" readonly>
              <div class="row row-cols-2">
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="id">Ticket</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" id="id" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="">Fecha estimada</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input class="form-control" name="fecha_termino_update" type="date">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="">Hora estimada</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input class="form-control" name="hora_Final_update" type="time">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label for="">Personal a asignar</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <select name="personal" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                    <option selected>Selecionar</option>
                    <option value="Juan">Juan</option>
                    <option value="maicol">Maicol</option>
                    <option value="pedro">Pedro</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <textarea name="observacion" id="observacion" class="form-control mt-2" rows="5" placeholder="Observacion del asignado"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" style="margin-right: auto;" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="actualizar" onclick="return insertJobs();">Ingresar trabajo</button>
            </form>
            <button id="doc" class="btn btn-info" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal" onclick="buscar_Modal()">Ver detalle</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el primer modal y me lo trae correctamente.

[image: Este es el primer modal y desde aquí quiero llamar al segundo modal pasándole variables]

Lo que trato es que, presionando el botón de "Ver detalle" del primer modal me llame al segundo modal pasando la variable de **TICKET** " y todo ese proceso a través de Ajax.

El código del Ajax que tengo es el siguiente.

```
<script>
       function buscar_Modal() {
        $('#modal_Segundo').modal({
          show:true
        });
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    $("#doc").click(function() {
        id_Ticket = $(this).attr("id")
        values = {
            "Ticket": id_Ticket,
            "bar": "0"
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: values,
            url: 'modal.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text', //dataType: 'text'
            cors: true,
        }).done(function(data) {
            data = $.trim(data.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, ''));
            console.log(data);
            $(id_Ticket).html(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
    });
});
}
</script>
```

El segundo modal desde la pagina "modal.php es el siguente"

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_Segundo">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">Modal 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <?php
        foreach ($ticket_con_levantamiento->list as $key => $value) {
        }
        **// Aqui quiero que muestres los datos pasados del ajax**
        $ticket = $GLOBALS['DB']->getTicket('37003');


        $ticket->getSkus();

        $ticket->getSeries();
        ?>

        <div class="m-2">
          <h2 type="text" class="text-center mb-5">Datos ticket <?= $ticket->getId(); ?></h2>
          <div class="row row-cols-2 col-md-12  responsive mb-5">
            <div class="col">
              <label for="region">Ticket</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['id_Ticket']["valor"] ?>" name="region" id="region" disabled>
              <!-- <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" id="id" readonly> -->
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="nombre_Cliente">Nombre cliente</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control  responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['nom_Cliente']["valor"] ?>" name="nombre_Cliente" id="nombre_Cliente" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col ">
              <label for="courier">Courier</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <?php if ($ticket->data['courier']["valor"] != "") { ?>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $ticket->data['courier']["valor"] ?>" name="courier" id="courier" disabled>
              <?php } else {
              ?>
                <input type="text" class="form-control  responsive" value="Sin courier ingresado " name="courier" id="courier" disabled>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="Comuna">Comuna</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['comuna']["valor"] ?>" name="comuna" id="comuna" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="region">Region</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['region']["valor"] ?>" name="region" id="region" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="direccion">Direccion</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['direccion']["valor"] ?>" name="direccion" id="direccion" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="fecha_Entrega_Estimada">Fecha termino estimada</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['fecha_Entrega_Estimada']["valor"] ?>" name="fecha_Entrega_Estimada" id="fecha_Entrega_Estimada" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="tel_Contacto">Telefono contacto</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control  responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['tel_Contacto']["valor"] ?>" name="tel_Contacto" id="tel_Contacto" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label for="courier">Responsable asignado</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" class="form-control  responsive" value="<?= $ticket->data['courier']["valor"] ?>" name="courier" id="courier" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php
          foreach ($ticket->detalle as $checkbox) {

            if (
              $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-GUARDAMOTOR-220V]" or $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-GUARDAMOTOR-380V]" or $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-GUARM-220V-2HP]"
              or $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-GUARM-220V-3HP]" or $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-LLAV-PART-220V]" or $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-LLAV-PART-380V]" or $checkbox['tarea'] == "[KIT-LLAV-PART-3TRI]"
            ) {
              write_to_console("consumo terminado");
            } else {
          ?>
              <div class="container-responsive mt-1" style="--bs-columns: 12;">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Observacion ingresada</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="2" disabled><?= $checkbox['observaciones'] ?></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
          <?php

            }
          }

          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" style="margin-right: auto;" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle" data-bs-toggle="modal">Volver al primero</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para terminar el error que me sale en consola es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para los que tengan dudas de donde me traigo la variable "TICKET" los traigo de la función eventClick del plugins FULL CALENDAR

```
 eventClick: function(info) {
          console.log(info);
          document.getElementById('id').value = info.event.id; //Le paso la variable ticket
          document.getElementById('start').value = info.event.start;
          document.getElementById('title').value = info.event.title;
          document.getElementById('startStr').value = info.event.startStr;

          $("#exampleModalToggle").modal("show"); //Aquí llamo al primer modal


   
        },
```

PD: Ta complejo la cosa, cualquier duda me dicen si necesitan más código o fotos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un enredo tremendo en tu código

En buscar_Modal() quieres abrir un modal que todavía no tienes, así que lo primero es buscar el modal. Pero no vamos a usar $.ajax, vamos a usar [load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) que es mucho mejor para este caso.

Otra cosa a considerar, es que no sé si se puede tener 2 modales abiertos a mismo tiempo usando boostrap, esto deberías averiguarlo

Lo primero es crear un div donde incluiremos el segundo modal

```
let modales=0;
function buscar_Modal() {
modales++;
  $("body").append(`<div id="modal_${modales}"></div>`); //creamos un div que va a contener el modal

 let idTicket = $("#doc").attr("id");

  $("#modal_" + modales).load(`modal.php?Ticket=${idTicket}&bar=0`, function(){
    //cuando terminó de cargar el segundo modal, recién lo podemos abrir
    $('#modal_Segundo').modal({
          show:true
    });
});
```